# Process in background mode trying to read from stdin

Tags: shell, linux-kernel

In Linux/Unix when a process in the background mode tries to read from stdin it gets terminated. What is causing this termination ? There is no core file. So it doesn't look like termination is by a signal that generates core.

Comment: I've never seen a process get terminated for trying to read from stdin when it's backgrounded. Are you thinking about the SIGTTIN and SIGTTOUT signals that are generated and *stop* (i.e. pause) the process instead?

Answer (score 0):

One reason for termination could be a signal.

When process are not connected directly to a tty device, stdin/stdout are typically handled with pipes.
The [pipe(7) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) says:

> If all file descriptors referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a `write(2)` will cause a `SIGPIPE` signal to be generated for the calling process.

However, this applies only to *writing*.

For reading,

> if all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have been closed, then an attempt to `read(2)` from the pipe will see end-of-file (`read(2)` will return 0).

It is quite possible that the program, when it cannot read anything, decides to terminate. (What else could it do?)